# Record from firebase query does not exist as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing an async function `async_unlike_post`, used for my firebase HTTP function `unlike_post` of the form in `index.js`. The implementation of `async_unlike_post` is stored in another file `posts.js`

**index.js**

```
exports.unlike_post = functions
  .https
  .onCall(async_unlike_post);
```

**posts.js**

```
const { admin, db } = require("../util/admin");
//admin.initializeApp(config);
//const db = admin.firestore();

const { uuid } = require("uuidv4");

const {
  success_response,
  error_response
} = require("../util/validators");



exports.async_unlike_post = async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const like_snapshot = await db
      .collection('likes')
      .where("liker_id", '==', req.liker_id)
      .where('entity_id', '==', req.entity_id)
      .limit(1).get();

    if (!like_snapshot.exists) {

      console.log("Case 1"); 

      return error_response("Post has not been liked by user");
    }

    const post_document = db.doc(`/posts/${req.entity_id}`);
    const post_snapshot = await post_document.get();

    if (!post_snapshot.exists) {

      console.log("Case 2");
      return error_response("Post not found");
    }

    console.log("Should delete");

    return db.collection("likes").doc(like_snapshot.id).delete();

  } catch (error) {
    return error_response(error);
  }
}



mockLike = {
  liker_id: "string1",
  entity_id: "string2"
}

exports.async_unlike_post(mockLike);
```

After running `node posts.js`, I am expecting to see the document in my Firestore database being deleted. However, on my console, it says it goes to Case 1. There is certainly a document in my firestore database in the `likes` collection with  the following attributes.

```
created_at: Some_timestamp,
entity_id: "string2",
liker_id: "string1",
type: "post"
```

Can someone enlighten me why does the execution of my code goes into Case 1?

Comment: How do you send `liker_id` and `entity_id` ? Did you try to log them to check for `undefined` ?

Comment: Just did, they are defined, `console.log` while running the function

Answer (score 0):

Your function takes parameters for `res` and `req`:

```
function asyncUnlikePost(req, res)
```

However, you are exporting an onCall function, which does not provide the same arguments:

```
exports.unlike_post = functions
  .https
  .onCall(async_unlike_post);
```

As you can see from the [documentation for callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), it provides a `data` and `context` parameters, not req and res.  onCall functions are different than onRequest functions.  They are not "compatible".

Also, this invocation here:

```
mockLike = {
  liker_id: "string1",
  entity_id: "string2"
}

exports.async_unlike_post(mockLike);
```

Isn't passing the required `res` and `req` parameters.  You're just passing some object instead.  That's not going to work.

Comment: I'm not sure if the problem arises from the `onCall` property of my function. I'm calling the async function instead of the one in `index.js`, hence I'm doing a write to the database directly from running my file. That would mean that passing a single argument makes `req` become the reference to the object, with defined parameters. I did a renaming of the parameters to (data, context) too, no difference in behaviour